# Game of life in F#

Tags: f#, game-of-life

First attempt at doing anything F#-y from a very heavy C# background, think I've grasped the fundamentals of FP, but always good to get other eyes on it:

```
namespace FSharp.GameOfLife

open System
open System.Drawing

module Array2D =
    let toArray (arr: 'T [,]) = arr |> Seq.cast<'T> |> Seq.toArray

module Array =
    let count (predicate: 'T -> bool) (arr: 'T[]) = arr |> Array.filter(predicate) |> Array.length

module Game =

    let (<&>) f g = (fun x -> f x && g x)

    type Cell (position) = 
        member this.Position = position
        member val IsAlive = false with get, set

    and Board (width : int, height : int) = 
        let grid = Array2D.init width height (fun x y -> Cell(System.Drawing.Point(x, y)))

        let withinBounds (x : int, y : int) =
            let insideWidth = width > x && x >= 0
            let insideHeight = height > y && y >= 0
            insideWidth && insideHeight

        let isSamePosition (cell : Cell, x : int, y : int) = 
            cell.Position = Point(x, y)

        let getNeighbours (grid : Cell[,]) (cell : Cell) =
            let isDifferentPosition (x, y) = not (isSamePosition (cell, x, y))
            let positionModifiers = Array2D.initBased -1 -1 3 3 (fun x y -> (cell.Position.X + x, cell.Position.Y + y))
            positionModifiers |> Array2D.toArray |> Array.filter (withinBounds <&> isDifferentPosition) |> Array.map (fun (x, y) -> grid.[x, y].IsAlive)

        member this.Grid with get() = grid

        member this.Tick() = 
            let cellWithNeighbourStates = this.Grid |> Array2D.map (fun cell -> (cell, (getNeighbours this.Grid cell))) |> Array2D.toArray
            cellWithNeighbourStates |> Array.iter (fun (cell, neighbours) -> 
                let liveNeighbours = neighbours |> Array.count (fun c -> c = true) 
                if cell.IsAlive then
                    cell.IsAlive <- 2 = liveNeighbours || 3 = liveNeighbours
                else
                    cell.IsAlive <- 3 = liveNeighbours
                )

        member this.SetAlive(cells : list<int * int>) =
            cells |> List.iter (fun (x, y) -> this.Grid.[y, x].IsAlive <- true)

        override this.ToString() = 
            let structs = this.Grid |> Array2D.map (fun cell -> if cell.IsAlive then "[]" else "()")
            let asRows = [|0..(height - 1)|] |> Array.map (fun row -> structs.[0.., row] |> Array.fold (fun acc elem -> sprintf "%s%s" acc elem) Environment.NewLine)
            asRows |> Array.fold (fun acc elem -> sprintf "%s%s" acc elem) Environment.NewLine
```

Can be tested as such:

```
open FSharp.GameOfLife.Game

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let board = Board (10, 10)

    //standard ocilator
    let x = board.SetAlive([
        (1, 1)
        (1, 2)
        (2, 1)
        (2, 2)
        (3, 3)
        (3, 4)
        (4, 3)
        (4, 4)
    ])

    printf "%s" (board.ToString())

    [|0..2|] |> Array.iter (fun _ -> 
        board.Tick()
        printf "%s" (board.ToString())
    )

    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the functions you created to work with arrays. There's no point in putting them in modules like that unless you're going to give the modules the `[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]` attribute.

You also didn't need the `Cell` type or that operator
You shouldn't use `and` to define your types unless they're mutually recursive.

```
open System
open System.Text

type Board (width : int, height : int) =
    let grid = Array2D.create width height false

    let withinBounds (x:int) (y:int) =
        (0 <= x  && x < width) && (0 <= y && y < height)

    let getNbs x y =
        ([| x-1,y+1; x,y+1; x+1,y+1;
            x-1,y  ;        x+1,y  ;
            x-1,y-1; x,y-1; x+1,y-1 |]
         |> Array.filter(fun (a,b) -> (withinBounds a b))
         |> Array.filter(fun (a,b) ->  grid.[a,b] = true)).Length

    member __.Item
        with get (x,y)   = grid.[x,y]
        and  set (x,y) v = grid.[x,y] <- v

    member __.Tick() =
        grid |> Array2D.iteri( fun x y alive ->
            let liveNeighbors = getNbs x y
            match alive with
            | true  -> grid.[x,y] <- liveNeighbors = 2 || liveNeighbors = 3
            | false -> grid.[x,y] <- liveNeighbors = 3
        )

    override __.ToString() =
        let frame = Array2D.zeroCreate height width
        grid |> Array2D.iteri(fun x y alive ->
                match alive with
                |true  -> frame.[height-1-y,x] <-"[@]"
                |false -> frame.[height-1-y,x] <-"[ ]"
        )
        let sb = StringBuilder()
        frame |> Array2D.iteri(fun _ y str ->
            match y = height-1 with
            | true  -> sb.Append(str).Append("\n") |> ignore
            | false -> sb.Append(str) |> ignore
        )
        sb.ToString()
```

The `__.Item` method gives you indexed acces into the board like this

```
let tb = Board(5,5) 
tb.[1,1] <- true
tb.[1,0] <- true
tb.[0,1] <- true
tb.[0,3] <- true
tb.[2,4] <- true
tb.[4,4] <- true

printfn "%A" tb 
tb.Tick()
printfn "%A" tb
tb.Tick()
printfn "%A" tb

[ ][ ][@][ ][@] 
[@][ ][ ][ ][ ] 
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] 
[@][@][ ][ ][ ] 
[ ][@][ ][ ][ ] 

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] 
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] 
[@][ ][ ][ ][ ] 
[@][ ][ ][ ][ ] 
[@][@][ ][ ][ ] 

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] 
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] 
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ] 
[@][@][ ][ ][ ] 
[@][@][ ][ ][ ]
```

There's no need to build and use the console to test this code, write your code in an .fsx and run it in FSI

Comment: Thanks! That `Cell` type was left over from the first attempt where I had it recursive, realised all I cared about was the bool, and forgot to remove it

Comment: Nice layout for the nearest neighbours array, a lot clearer as to what I'm trying to achieve there.  The `Item` method was a useful tip.